# Why won't my jQuery animate effect work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

this is the html, all in the head:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

where the 2nd is my js document!!
The js document looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("li").fadeTo(0, 0.6),

    $("li").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).fadeTo(100, 1),
        $(this).animate({top: "-=20px"},"fast")
    });
    $("li").mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).fadeTo(100, 0.6),
        $(this).animate({top: "=20px"},"fast")
    });


});
```

The opacity works, but not the animation, what is wrong?

Comment: You are missing a `+` from `top: "=20px"`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your `<li>` elements need to have a position value of `fixed`, `relative` or `absolute` if you are animating the `top` CSS. Without it, the animation will still complete, but you won't see any visual effect in the browser.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("li").fadeTo(0, 0.6),

    $("li").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).fadeTo(100, 1),
        $(this).animate({top: "-=20px"},"fast")
    });
    $("li").mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).fadeTo(100, 0.6),
        $(this).animate({top: "=20px"},"fast")
    });


});
```

```css
li {
    position:absolute;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Or `fixed` or `relative`. `absolute` would put all list elements on top of each other so that's probably not a good choice.

Comment: Cool, but the code is obviously broken as evidenced by the code snippet.

Comment: Like, it has all the items on top of each other like I said, and if you hover over them they fly off the screen and never come back.

Comment: Yes, this is expected for `absolute`, as you noted.

Comment: @Juhana the root issue is the position property, how to make the animation show visually, nothing to do with how to make a pretty animation. Besides, OP has provided no info on how this should display, there are a million possibilities. This answers the question "Why won't my jQuery animate effect work?".